# val ... get() {...} in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

From the Kotlin Koan question(
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-koans/blob/master/src/ii_collections/n16FlatMap.kt), I have this Koan code. How do I read this? It looks like a variable with `val`, but it is a function with a `()` and `{}`.

```
val Customer.orderedProducts: Set<Product> get() {
    // Return all products this customer has ordered
    todoCollectionTask()
}
```

Comment: looks like an implicit getter

Comment: Documented at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a read-only computed extension property. The `get` method is what's called to compute the value.

It can be used thus:

```
yourCustomer.orderedProducts.first()
               // ^ You're implicitly calling the get() method.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to allow the opportunity to process the members as a property. In this example, I can get the string from the `Customer.orderedProducts` property.

```
data class Customer(val name: String, val orders: List<String>)

val Customer.orderedProducts: String get() {
    return this.orders.joinToString()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val c = Customer("hello", arrayListOf("A", "B"))
    println(c.orderedProducts)
    println(c.orders)
}
```

These are output values.

```
A, B
[A, B]
```